# Use AlexNet instead of LeNet model in Siamese Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have successfully used  LeNet model to train my own dataset using Siamese Network using this [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html). Now I want to use AlexNet as I believe it is more powerful than LeNet. Can someone provide guidelines or tutorial to use the AlexNet in Siamese Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through this [github](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) repository. Specially the models and examples section. You can get the implementation of [AlexNet](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks) in caffe [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet).

N.B. Please don't flag this post because of its length or sharing link. Links that I shared in this answer contains large code which I cannot post as an answer.

Comment: Why I get a negative vote, I believe it is pretty valid question and I did homework before I post the question @Wasi Ahmad

Comment: not sure, may be some people find the question not suitable for stackoverflow!

Comment: I believe this is very interesting. Two AlexNet for Siamese Network https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/jc0Jx4JjWwo